# Stop views overlapping horizontally in a relative layout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have two views, a day view and a event view as part of a calendar. I want my events to fill the day view in width (which is working) but when I add another at the same position/time I want them to split the width... I am adding my event dynamically using java. Is there an attribute I can use so that views don't overlap?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/dayView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/day_view">

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ie.test.calendar.CalendarEventView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/eventView"
android:background="@drawable/event_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</ie.test.calendar.CalendarEventView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Linier layout as parent view with horizontal orientation. And also use concept of weight for width. It will devide your parent view according to child quantity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

You could set rules at runtime, using ID's.

```
layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.id1)
```

Although, i think, that using `LinearLayout` would be much simpler.

Comment: So I would have to know at the time of inserting the first event that there is an event going to be added in the same position?? and then make space for it?